# Displaying text after login

Tags: firebase

I am designing a math problem site using Firebase and I want to display a problem when someone logs in.

What I want in pseudo code is,

```
if user logged in
document.write([problem])
else
document.write(Please login to see the problem)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When using Firebase Simple Login, upon instantiation of the FirebaseAuthClient you will define a callback function that is invoked any time the login state of the user changes.

From https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html:

```
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com');
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  if (user) {
    // user authenticated with Firebase
  } else if (error) {
    // an error occurred authenticating the user
  } else {
    // user is logged out
  }
});
```

For your case, if you have a user object, you can hide any login-related UI and show the problem, otherwise, hide the problem and show any login-related UI.

Then, to log users in, choose one or more of the Firebase Simple Login authentication providers, configure that provider in Forge (accessed via `https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com`) and attempt to authenticate the user via:

```
authClient.login(<provider>, <options>);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: So I should write as,                                                     `var chatRef = new Firebase('https://<myfirebase>.firebaseIO-demo.com');
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  if (user) {
    document.write("Factor x^2+2x+1")
  } else if (error) {
    document.write("An error occurred while logging you in.Try again.")
  } else {
    document.write("Please login to see the problem")
  }
});` Is that all?

Comment: @ShenalSanthush After replacing `<myfirebase>.firebaseIO-demo.com` with your Firebase URL (somename.firebaseio.com), that looks good for monitoring user authentication state. Then, call `authClient.login(...)` once a user clicks the login button in your application.

Comment: @ShenalSanthush To see a complete example of email / password authentication using Firebase Simple Login, see [https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US&fromgroups=#!topic/firebase-talk/POcs7m5gihg](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US&fromgroups=#!topic/firebase-talk/POcs7m5gihg).

Comment: I used the following code to create a register button `<button onclick="var chatRef = new Firebase('https://<myname>.firebaseio.com');
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  authClient.createUser(email, password, function(error, user) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log('User Id: ' + user.id + ', Email: ' + user.email);
  }
});">Register</button>` (I used <myname> for security purposes)
But when I click the button,nothing happens.Why?

Comment: @ShenalSanthush Ensure that you have enabled email / password authentication for your Firebase in Forge (accessible at `<yourfirebase>.firebaseio.com`. Then, try logging the error field to see if there is anything invalid about your arguments to that method.