# AngularJS and Firebase Authentication

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security, angularjs-authentication

I would like to add an authentication mechanism to my AngularJS app with Firebase backend. The requirements are simple:

- Authenticated users should be able to access any page.
- If unauthenticated users goes to `/some_page` (any page except `/login`), they should be redirected to `/login`. Once they enter the right credentials, they should be redirected to back to `/other_page`.

Possible solution that is described [here](http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application) makes the following assumption:

> My solution assumes the following server side behaviour: for every
>   /resources/* call, if user is not authorized, response a 401 status

But, I'm not sure if it is possible to enforce this behavior when using Firebase as a backend.

Any help and/or examples to implement such AngularJS+Firebase integration will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to do your routing on the client side with the [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) service.

When a user authenticates through Firebase, save some record of this on the client, like in localstorage, some all-encompassing controller, or your own Angular [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services) (my preferred option).

In your routing controller, if the user is authenticated, redirect to `/some_page`, otherwise redirect to `/login` and keep track of the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location) where the user intended to go.

If, on the other hand, you want to route with your server, you could use the solution you linked to by [having your server generate Firebase auth tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15024253/247243)

Comment: Hi bennlich,  are you mean store the auth info which returned from FirebaseAuthClient in Angular service ($rootScope). So next time we just get the info from $rootScope without calling FirebaseAuthClient?

Comment: @vzhen see my answer to your SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026374/angularjs-should-i-rootscope-data-returned-from-firebase/17029756#17029756. In general it is better to share data through a service than through $rootScope (for modularity's sake and so that your $rootScope properties aren't accidentally overwritten).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement recently and came across this blog post.
http://www.42id.com/articles/firebase-authentication-and-angular-js/

It explains setting up an Angular JS application that interacts with Firebase. Also included are ways to authenticate against OAuth providers such as Google+ and Github using Firebase API, routing based on authentication status, storing user profile information on Firebase and setting up security rules on Firebase to protect user data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase Simple Login (rather than generating the authentication tokens on your own servers), you can see how to detect your login state client-side here:
[Displaying text after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935130/displaying-text-after-login)