# AngularJS: How to hide the template content until user is authenticated?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security, angularjs-routing, angularjs-authentication

My app has 2 pages: `main.html` and `login.html`.
When not authenticated users go to `/main` they should be redirected to `/login`.

The problem is that `main.html` is rendered first, and after a second or so, when user authentication fails, `login.html` is rendered.

How could I prevent from `main.html` to be rendered until authentication succeeds?

Here is the relevant code (CoffeeScript):

```
angular.module('myApp', [...])
.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when '/login',
    templateUrl: 'html/login.html'
    controller: LoginController

  $routeProvider.otherwise
    templateUrl: 'html/main.html'
    controller: MainController
])
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'appService', ($rootScope, $location, app) ->
  $rootScope.$on '$locationChangeStart', (event, newValue, oldValue) ->
    return if newValue == '/login'

    $.when(app.authenticate()).fail ->
      $location.path '/login'
      $rootScope.$apply()
])
```

---

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory 'appService' , () ->
  rootRef = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com')

  user: null
  authenticate: ->
    deferred = $.Deferred()

    authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient rootRef, (error, user) =>
      if error
        # An error occurred while attempting login
        @user = null
        deferred.reject()
      else if user
        # User authenticated with Firebase
        @user = user
        deferred.resolve()
      else
        # User is logged out
        @user = null
        deferred.reject()

    deferred.promise()
```

Comment: Misha, it seems like my answer is not what you were looking for. Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't serve the template (in your case `main.html`) until the user is authenticated. I have a customized function on server for serving templates, which checks if the user is authenticated. If in the function I find out the user is not logged in, it returns response with 401 status code. In angular code I then hold the request until the authentication and then ask for the template again.

I was inspired to do this by this post: http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the same requirement was to define the following watch:

```
$rootScope.$watch(
    function() {
        return $location.path();
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {  
        if (newValue != '/login' && user is not logged in) {
            $location.path('/login');  
        }
    },
    true);
```

in a controller associated with the body element of the index page (i. e. the page containing the `ng-view` directive).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to hide the normal DOM and show an "Authenticating..." message, maybe with a spinner, to give the user some idea of why he/she is sitting there waiting for something to happen. In main.html, include something like:

```
<spinner ng-hide="appService.wrapper.user"></spinner>
<!-- everything else ng-show="appService.wrapper.user" -->
```

where `<spinner></spinner>` is an Angular [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that is replaced by your custom "Authenticating..." message, and `user` is a variable your appService makes available to `MainController`. Note that you may need to wrap `user` in an object within appService, like so:

```js
.service('appService', function() {

  var wrapper = {
    user: null
  };

  function authenticate() {
    // start the authentication and return the promise,
    // but modify wrapper.user instead of user
  }

  return wrapper;

});
```

You'll also need to store either `appService` or `appService.wrapper` in the `$scope` variable of your `MainController`.