# What is the best way to create a simple auth using firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, firebase

I've read the firebase tutorial but frankly this is not make sense yet, sorry about that =)

I wanna to implement a simple auth, just my username and password, that the credentials are in a node in my firebase structure (I don't wanna auth using Facebook, Email/Pass or some like that)

What is the good way to do this using?

Comment: http://engineering.letsnurture.com/firebase-basic-authentication/

Answer (score 6):

Firebase clients are authenticated using a secure token called a JWT. This JWT must be generated by a trusted server somewhere (it cannot be generated on your clients, or we couldn't verify that it's authenticate).

If you want specifically to authenticate with a username (not email) and password, and you want to store the authentication credentials (a hashed password for instance), in Firebase, you can do that but you'll need a server somewhere to compare the password someone enters in your app with that hashed password and then generate a custom JWT token. See the docs here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html

To avoid making developers run server code for this common case, we provide a service called Firebase Simple Login that will generate these tokens for you. It works for Email/Password, Facebook, Twitter, and some other common login types. You can see documentation here. https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.       
Now using the Firebase tutorial I'm trying to do a single authentication example where I have three pages, my sign up, sign in and index (the last I wanna to provide only to users authenticated).     

I still do not understand how it works, do you have some example where I can clarify this things?

Comment: Here is an example of email and password auth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167981/how-do-i-use-firebase-simple-login-with-email-password

Answer (score 0):

You could try this question which is similiar [AngularJS and Firebase Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000919/angularjs-and-firebase-authentication) or this Tutorial on Firebase auth which looks fairly straight forward.[Tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-persona.html)

If you still have no luck, I suggest posting some code showing how far you have got and I will see what I can do to help.