# Angularjs should I $rootScope data returned from firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-scope

Let say I want to retrieve user info from firebase,
and this user info will be displayed in several routes/controllers

Should I `$rootScope` the returned user info?

**or**

Call below code in each controller?

```
firebaseAuth.firebaseRef.child('/people/' + user.id).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  $scope.user = snapshot.val();
})
```

**UPDATE**

I have a following service with a `getUserInfo()` function then what is the best way
to use it in several controllers?
calling `firebaseAuth.getUserInfo().then()` in each controller?
If the user data I have to use in several controller. Why don't I set it `$rootScope`?
So I don't need to call it again and again in different controllers.

```
myapp.service('firebaseAuth', ['$rootScope', 'angularFire', function($rootScope, angularFire) {
  this.firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com");
  this.getUserInfo = function(id) {
    var userRef = this.firebaseRef.child('/human/' + id);
    var promise = angularFire(userRef, $rootScope, 'user', {});
    return promise;
  }
});
```

Comment: You can find some working examples in [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire), Firebase's official Angular lib.

Comment: @Kato I think my question is not clear vague, I updated. Please check it again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of AngularFire is to keep your javascript data model in sync with Firebase at all times. You don't want to create a new AngularFire promise every time you need to fetch data. You just initialize AngularFire once, and your local data will always be up to date.

```js
myapp.service('firebaseAuth', ['angularFireCollection', function(angularFireCollection) {
    this.firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com");
    this.initUserInfo = function(id) {
        if (!this.userRef) {
            this.userRef = this.firebaseRef.child('/human/' + id);
            this.userInfo = angularFireCollection(this.userRef);
        }
        else {
            // already initialized
        }
    }
}]);
```

Remember that all properties of your service (i.e. everything you assign using the `this` keyword) are accessible from controllers injected with this service. So you can do things like `console.log(firebaseAuth.userInfo)` or `firebaseAuth.userRef.on('value', function(snap) { ... });`

Also, you may eventually want to use the [FirebaseAuthClient](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) for your user authentication.

Comment: But if you access directly using `firebaseAuth.userInfo`. How do you assign the id param?

Comment: You first have to use firebaseAuth.initUserInfo(id). Are you familiar with the way I've declared the function? `var moose = function() { ... }` is similar to `function moose() { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a service to perform the authentication and store the user data.  Then you can inject the service into any controller that needs access to the user.

Comment: Where should I store the data?   variable?